# What's the difference between discovery and confirmation of an external address?

Tags: rust, networking, network-programming, p2p, libp2p

In [`rust-libp2p`](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p) (specifically `libp2p-swarm` 0.43.3), there are two swarm events, `FromSwarm::NewExternalAddrCandidate` and `FromSwarm::ExternalAddrConfirmed`, and the [documentation](https://docs.rs/libp2p-swarm/0.43.3/libp2p_swarm/behaviour/enum.FromSwarm.html#variant.NewExternalAddrCandidate) describes them as such:

> `NewExternalAddrCandidate(NewExternalAddrCandidate<'a>)`
> Informs the behaviour that we have discovered a new candidate for an external address for us.

> `ExternalAddrConfirmed(ExternalAddrConfirmed<'a>)`
> Informs the behaviour that an external address of the local node was confirmed.

**What's the meaningful difference between *discovery* of an external address and *confirmation* of one?**